# Minikube+docker on Vagrant

Tags: docker, vagrant, minikube, ubuntu-22.04

Host:
Windows 10x64 22h2,
Vagrant version 2.3.7.
Virtual:
Ubuntu Server 2204,
Docker version 24.0.4, build 3713ee1,
Minikube version: v1.31.0.

Hi, need help installing minikube via vagrant. As a docker driver.
The problem is that when I run the minicube, it wants to run docker, but docker requires sudo. And the command "sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}" requires a password.
The task is to automate the process and create a finished Vagrantfile with a working mimicube based on Docker.

[github](https://github.com/kadannrheim/devops/tree/4cb17cf2db4d5c307fec4f6cd6ab8a7dc62f06a7/MANUALS/vagrant/vg_minikube_us2204)

`sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}` but it requires a password

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved, I registered the username instead of a variable `sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}` = `sudo usermod -aG docker vagrant`